# Java getting error while executing Adb Commands using process builder

Tags: java, android, cmd, adb

When Executing following line I am getting response error=> segmentation fault

```
 String[] commands = {"cmd.exe","/c","adb shell","su","cd /data/app","ls com.mypack*"};
 StringBuilder cmdReturnRsp = new StringBuilder();
 try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        processBuilder.directory(fileADb);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
               cmdReturnRsp.append((char) c);
        }
        System.out.println("responce = "+ cmdReturnRsp);
  }catch(Exception e){

  }
```

but when above lines run in cmd prompt it is working fine, so How can make code work same as cmd

[image: CMD commnads snapshot]

Comment: before rating it negative do mention the problem with it.

Comment: The question is OK, I upvoted it to compensate somebody's downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missunderstanding of process builder. I seems that you think that it works as a kind of script. This is wrong. Process builder just builds correct command line and executes it.

So, you can run `cmd.exe`, you can run `cmd.exe /c adb shell`, but I doubt you can run the rest of commands.

Take a look on description of `adb`. If it supports mode similar to `cmd /c`, i.e. gets commands in command line and then executes it you can probably do this.

BTW, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Obviously. I think you did not understand what I wanted to say. Again, if `adb` supports mode similar to `/c` of `cmd`, use it together with `/c`. So, cmd will run adb, adb will run the next commands.

Comment: I tried to find the meaning of /c command but couldnot find any help.. can you tell what exactly /c does?

Comment: I have to install android application to my rooted device from java desktop app as system application.. thatswhy I need this

Comment: `/c` runs command followed after it in context of the new shell (cmd).

Comment: -c has the same purpose as /c/... thanks for your help and hints    @AlexR

Comment: Yes, `-c` is supported by unix shells like sh, csh, bash, ksh etc. Is it supported by `adb` too?

Comment: yes in shell commands... here is example command                                adb shell su -c \'mount -o rw,remount /system\

Answer (score -2):

Check if device is rooted, usually when device is not rooted, It does not work.

Comment: if device was not rooted than how commands in cmd prompt works fine??

Comment: If you don't stop down voting people down, you will not get any answers to your issues. Good luck

Comment: I did not down vote any one.... my question also have been down voted 3 or 4 time

Comment: and also you should carefully read full question before answering

Answer (score -3):

/c is not understood I guess.
It should be cd c:/

Comment: no there is no problem with it... it is working correctly until 'su' commands execute... segmentation error is on 'su' command